# firewall has blocked ssh

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall

I want to connect to remote amazon aws service(EC2 instance) , and I would like to be able to ssh  to it from my laptop while using the campus provided network (which has cyberoam firewall).  However, they have pretty much every port blocked and ssh won't work.  Is there anything i can do? does ssh run through port 80? I don't really know what to do .

All it says is : " ssh_exchange_identification: read: Software caused connection abort "

ssh works elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to modify the sshd service on your EC2 instance, you can add a post to listen on.  I wouldn't recomment using 80, but perhaps another one going outbound is open.

[Man Page for sshd_config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config)

Example update to /etc/sshd_config

```
Port 22
Port 80
Port 32022
```

Answer (score 0):

SSH runs on Port 22, unless you ask the Technicians there to enable port 22 or allow you access to it then you won't be able to access it from their network.

I guess you can be unethical about it, but I can not advise how.